# Core Data Condition

Tags: swift, core-data

I need to add a Core Data condition How do I do it? . If the record is in this condition, the "sonuc" variable will be true

Core data model:

[image]

> If "kullaniciadi" is "emre" and "otogiris" is "1" then the "sonuc" will
>   be true

```
func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        } else {
            return DatabaseController.managedObjectContext
        }
    }



func otomatikGirisKontrol() -> Bool
    {
        var sonuc = false
        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Kullanicilar")
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do{
            let results = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
            if results.count > 0
            {
            sonuc = true
            }
            else
            {
            sonuc = false
            }

        }
       catch
          {

          }
        return (sonuc)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `NSPredicate` to fetch only `Kullaniciar` objects fitting your condition:

```
let fetchRequest = ...

let kullaniciadi = "emre"
let otogiris = "1"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "kullaniciadi = %@ AND otogiris = %@", kullaniciadi, otogiris)

request.predicate = predicate

//... execute fetch request
```